# Extracting rows from file based on another file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files.

File 1:

```
SNP Allele1 Allele2 Effect  StdErr  PVAL    Direction   HetISq  HetChiSHetDf    HetPVal
rs12266638  t   g   0.4259  0.0838  3.776e-07   +?  0.0 0.000   0   1
rs7995014   t   c   2.2910  0.5012  4.853e-06   +?  0.0 0.000   0   1
```

File 2:

```
Chromosome Position SNP EA NEA EAF BETA SE P Direction
10 108627406 rs12266638 t g 0.991 -0.2649 0.0578 4.608e-06 -
11 116365828 rs112127824 a t 0.0327 0.4569 0.0994 4.327e-06 +
```

I would like to print a file 3, based on the "SNP" column. If the SNP exists in file 2, I would like to print the whole row with all columns of file 1.

Output:

```
rs12266638  t   g   0.4259  0.0838  3.776e-07   +?  0.0 0.000   0   1
```

I tried the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; if(NR==1) print $0} ($1 in a) {print a[$1]}' file 1 file 2 > file 3
```

But it prints different SNPs than those present in file 2.

Comment: You will read a lot of time the file2, use any language to load in ram file 2 and index by SNP

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: It will depend a lot of the language you are confident to use and the size of the files

Comment: Do you really not want the header line from file1 to appear in file3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$3]; next} FNR> 1 && $1 in a' file2 file1

rs12266638  t   g   0.4259  0.0838  3.776e-07   +?  0.0 0.000   0   1
```

Comment: Given `if(NR==1) print $0` from the OPs code I think they actually do want the header line printed too, despite it not appearing in the expected output, which obviously makes your ode simpler (remove `FNR> 1 && `).

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution which works for any position of the SNP field:

```
# SO71009277.awk
BEGIN {
  fnr = 0
  while ((getline < ARGV[2]) > 0) {
    ++fnr
    if (fnr == 1) {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        FIELDBYNAME2[$i] = i # e.g. FIELDBYNAME2["SNP"] = 3
    }
    else {
      SNP_KEY[$FIELDBYNAME2["SNP"]]
    }
  }
  close(ARGV[2])

  fnr = 0
  while ((getline < ARGV[1]) > 0) {
    ++fnr
    if (fnr == 1) {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        FIELDBYNAME1[$i] = i # e.g. FIELDBYNAME1["SNP"] = 1
    }
    else {
      if ($FIELDBYNAME1["SNP"] in SNP_KEY)
        print $0
    }
  }
  close(ARGV[1])
}
```

Call:

```
awk -f SO71009277.awk file1.txt file2.txt
=>
rs12266638  t   g   0.4259  0.0838  3.776e-07   +?  0.0 0.000   0   1
```

---

Edit by Ed Morton - if you want to do the above using more idiomatic awk, it'd be:

```
FNR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        fieldByName[(NR==FNR),$i] = i
    }
    next
}
NR == FNR {
    snpKey[$(fieldByName[1,"SNP"])] = $0
    next
}
$(fieldByName[0,"SNP"]) in snpKey {
    print snpKey[$(fieldByName[0,"SNP"])]
}
```

Comment: About 1 third of your script is hard-coding things that awk does for you by default, i.e. a loop reading lines, setting and incrementing FNR, and closing files. A major reason to use awk is so you don't have to write code to do all the things like those that are commonly required when processing text.

Comment: Absolutely right, but personally I prefer code that also works with other programming languages (which few adjustments) and is better understandable than specific constructs like 'FNR==NR' etc.

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I added an idiomatic awk script so anyone reading your answer can see the difference and make a decision on what they prefer when writing their own code. If you do mind, feel free to delete it. FWIW, I wouldn't really read `file1` first and save it in memory, I'd just store the SNP values from `file2` first and print the matching line(s) from `file1` while reading it second.

Comment: Thank you, of course I don't mind! I appreciate your alternative code. The future reader shall decide which code is better readable. As for your comment, you are right. I have changed the SO71009277.awk code to work more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big the dataset is, this should be fairly fast, only accessing each file once. Granted, not on a system where I can compare at the moment, so mostly a hunch. A solution like this is probably only suitable if the amount of unique identifiers isn't very large, though.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
snp_expression=$(awk 'FNR>1{print $3}' file_2 | sort -u | paste -sd "|")
grep -E "^(${snp})[[:space:]]" file_1 > file_3
```